# Как открыть файл в пакете?

Tags: java

Java я начал учить не так давно, так что вполне возможно что мой вопрос очень и очень глуп.
У меня есть пакет src, внутри которого находится еще один пакет - files.

- В пакете files лежит file.txt с рандомным текстом,
- В пакете src находится класс MainClass (внутри которого - метод main)

Я хочу считать текст, что находится в file.txt с помощью MainClass и вывести текст на консоль.
Гугл мне предлагал разные варианты, но все они не находили мой file.txt! 
Как мне это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Начните читать книгу Хорстмана 1 том. Вот [тут](http://devcolibri.com/1141) подробно написано, что и как делать. Уже изъезженный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, и за ссылку. То как советуют сделать в статье - у меня получается. Но мне нужно чтобы мне файл находило без полного пути. У меня файл находится по этому пути: C:\Users\Evertum\src\files
и если указывать его полностью - то оно находит. И все работает.

Но я хочу указать только files\file.txt 
как такое сделать? и возможно ли такое?

Comment: Относительно корня проекта не получается указать? `File file = new File("src/files/file.txt");` или как там у вас `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file.getPath()));`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило J2EE приложение файлы внутрь себя не пишет. Файл либо находится вне приложения, либо вместо файла используется база....

Например если вы сделаете создание файла, как в примере, который дал Владимир в комментарии

```js
public static void write(String fileName, String text) {
    //Определяем файл
    File file = new File(fileName);
 
    try {
        //проверяем, что если файл не существует то создаем его
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
 
        //PrintWriter обеспечит возможности записи в файл
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
 
        try {
            //Записываем текст у файл
            out.print(text);
        } finally {
            //После чего мы должны закрыть файл
            //Иначе файл не запишется
            out.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

то вызвав метод и указав в аргументах так:

```
FileWorker.write("myfile.txt", "my Test Text");
```

увидите, что он будет создан аж вне папки `src` проекта. Точнее прям в той же папке, что и `src`

Отсюда рекомендация: делать папки с ресурсами и сохранение вне проекта. И указывать путь уже относительно них, т.е. по факту построенный проект (`jar` файл к примеру) будет корнем.

Либо указывать абсолютный путь.

Для непостроенного проекта можно указать путь начиная от корня, т.е.

```
File file = new File("src/files/file.txt"); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file.getPath())); 
и т.д.
```

Но максимум это использовать если это просто для себя и для тестов. Не более того. Хотя я все равно не рекомендую. Лучше сразу делать по-человечески))

Ибо надо знать, что после создания, к примеру `jar` - папки `src` не будет. Поэтому появятся проблемы с этим путём))  Отсюда и рекомендация, которая была выше.